# sorting categories in a highcharter stacked column chart

Tags: r, sorting, highcharts, r-highcharter, columnsorting

I have a Highcharter stacked column chart here and i want to sort the grouping (category) according to the order in the dataset (Z, E, A).
But Highcharter sorts the segments alphabetically (A, E, Z).
Is there any way to sort the segments from Z->A?

Many thanks for any help.

```
install.packages("highcharter")
library(highcharter)

# data frame
city <- c("New York","New York","New York","Boston","Boston","Boston","Washington","Washington","Washington", "Seattle","Seattle","Seattle", "Houston", "Houston", "Houston") 
value <- c(1000,2500,2600,1900,1800,500,4900, 2000,3000,4000,5000,1500,1300,1400,1850)
category <- c("Z", "E", "A","Z", "E", "A","Z", "E", "A","Z", "E", "A","Z", "E", "A")
data <- data_frame(city, value, category)

#View(data)

# higcharter stacked column
hc <- data %>%
  hchart('column', hcaes(x= city, y = value, group = category)) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking='normal'))%>%
  hc_title(text='Stacked Chart',style = list(fontWeight = "", fontSize = "15px"))  
hc
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no such options from the default, but I think it could be created using the custom logic in formatter function available from the Highcharts API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Here you can find an article showing how to work with Highcharts JavaScript syntax in R: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/?fbclid=IwAR39-dztCuBUrncLQHEo9yNin00lRZfSqKY1JqAdvMU7KkokZGfTfj5DYB4